# Linking Tensforflow in Visual Studio project

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, tensorflow

I've built TensorFlow with GPU Support (lastest stable version 1.10.1) with CUDA 9 and CUDNN 7.0. After that, when I link the shared libs which it's built and including the headers, I have always the next errors:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

The main problem appear in "logging.h" file at this directive:

```
TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(Check_EQ,
                    ==)  // Compilation error with CHECK_EQ(NULL, x)?
TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(Check_NE, !=)  // Use CHECK(x == NULL) instead.
TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(Check_LE, <=)
TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(Check_LT, <)
TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(Check_GE, >=)
TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(Check_GT, >)
#undef TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL
```

So, I don't understand what is happening, so anyone had similar troubles?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you've already built it, if these are defining things you aren't using in your code then you could try just commenting out the lines that don't compile and see if you can get away without them? But to fix this it looks like you'll need to work through the macros and work out what's missing, and see if you can understand why it was defined when you built Tensorflow in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

It is a problem of MSVC. You should add an `#define NOMINMAX` on top of your source file.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow currently does not support being built on Windows (see [Installing Tensorflow from Sources](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources)).